# Multiple async actions inside a single vert.x handler

Tags: java, rest, web-services, asynchronous, vert.x

I'm using Java vert.x as my REST service.
I'm having a single vertical, which has a single endpoint, let's call it
"/Foo"

inside the Foo-Handler, in the "handle" method, I need to call to WebService-A and WebService-B, merge both of the answers and return it as the response.

how can I run 2 parts completely async from inside a single handler?
Is there a better way to do this? I thought maybe to create a vertical for handling A and another vertical for B, and a third vertical to wrap those two, but i'm not sure this is correct...

I can also create new Thread for each operation, but again, I believe there is a built-in solution from the vert.x infra that I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [async coordination](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_async_coordination). In particular, [concurrent compostion](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_concurrent_composition), lets you merge the results of two or more asynchronous operations.